# Ionic get installed apps on android device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm new at ionic framework and mobile apps, Is there any plugin or method to get list of installed apps on android devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed a ready-made Cordova plugin available that gives the list of installed apps in the device.  This [AppList Plugin](https://github.com/jmrezayi2/Applist) should help you out.

Infact it gives the app icon as well.

UPDATE: There are no such ready-made plugin available yet for iOS as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you i am already using that now , but i have faced a problem while adding the plugin .

Comment: @RaisoMos Have you included cordova.js file in your HTML and registered deviceready event

Comment: Did you get it working? cause i am stuck in same situation, will be glad if you can help me out. Thanks

Comment: @sumitchauhan if you could tell me what exactly is the issue you are facing i can check

Comment: Do you know of any that are compatible with iOS?

Comment: @lams unfortunately i dont see any readymade plugin for iOS... one reason could be due to the complexity in the implementation given the security constraints in iOS. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
import * as Applist from 'cordova-plugin-applist2/www/Applist.js';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
```

to your component .ts file

Then to use it in probably constructor

```
constructor(public platform: Platform) {
  platform.ready().then(
    function(){
      if(platform.is('android') && !platform.is('mobileweb')){
          var success = function(app_list) { 
            //success function
            console.log(app_list);
           };
          var error = function(app_list) {  
            //error          
            console.log("An Error occured while fetching App Lists");
            console.error(app_list);
          };
          //for the date parameters, any date is okay, 
          //the first date should be in the past
          Applist.createEvent('', '', '', new Date(1999, 10, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12), new Date(), success, error);
      }
    }
  );
}
```