# Ionic get installed apps on android device with icon

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I know this question is already asked but I have problem in that solution which is not answered there.

I used [this](https://github.com/jmrezayi2/Applist) plugin but this gives me error:

```
var success = function (app_list) { alert(JSON.stringify(app_list)); };
var error = function (app_list) { alert("Oopsie! " + app_list); };
Applist.createEvent('', '', '', '', '', success, error)
```

How can I remove this error? I downloaded it running:

```
npm i cordova-plugin-applist
```

Error message:

```
Cannot find name 'Applist'
```

Comment: It might help if you refer to where this question was already asked

Comment: Thanks for reply
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688616/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-apps-along-with-the-icons-android-in-phonegap

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501564/ionic-get-installed-apps-on-android-device

Comment: The Typescript compiler doesn't recognise where `AppList` is coming from. Try adding `import { Applist } from 'cordova-plugin-applist/www/Applist.js';` to the top of the file

Comment: I did it then it shows error 

**Cannot read property 'createEvent' of undefined**

Comment: My bad, change it to `import * as Applist from 'cordova-plugin-applist/www/Applist.js';`

Comment: It again show this Error 
_WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_cordova_plugin_applist_www_Applist_js__.createEvent is not a function

Comment: when i change import from 
`import * as Applist from 'cordova-plugin-applist/www/Applist.js'`
to `import * as Applist from '../../plugins/cordova-plugin-applist2/www/Applist.js';`
Error changed to `cordova is not defined in  Applist.js:3`

Comment: I am still looking for solution....

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
import * as Applist from 'cordova-plugin-applist2/www/Applist.js';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
```

to your component .ts file

Then to use it in probably constructor

```
constructor(public platform: Platform) {
  platform.ready().then(
    function(){
      if(platform.is('android') && !platform.is('mobileweb')){
          var success = function(app_list) { 
            //success function
            console.log(app_list);
           };
          var error = function(app_list) {  
            //error          
            console.log("An Error occured while fetching App Lists");
            console.error(app_list);
          };
          //for the date parameters, any date is okay, 
          //the first date should be in the past
          Applist.createEvent('', '', '', new Date(1999, 10, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12), new Date(), success, error);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Then this showed me this error.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51008281/ionic-get-installed-apps-on-android-device-with-icon/60859314#comment89009761_51008281

Comment: Sure, will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: @HarrySattar are you able display the icon on the screen?